# Redox reaction: Iron(III) and Iodide ion

Tags: redox

I'm a real beginner in chemistry and I'm currently reading about redox reactions. I'm quite confused about this simple redox reaction:

> ${\text{Iron(III) ion + Iodide ion} \rightleftharpoons \text {Iron(II) ion + Iodine}}$
>   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> \text{Oxidation numbers}& +3 & -1 &\rightleftharpoons & -1 & 0\\ \hline
>  & Fe^{3+}& I^-&\rightleftharpoons & Fe^{2+}&I_2\\ \hline
> \end{array}

I understand the principles of transferring electrons. But how would I come from the upper formula to the result that the Iodine exists two times on the right side? After reading the reaction formula I would have written the Iodine just once (not as seen here twice).

Comment: You wouldn't. The fact has nothing to do with this reaction (or redox reactions in general, or any other reactions, for that matter). It is just that elementary iodine exists as I2.

Comment: Thank you. If you want, you can write that as an answer, I would accept it then.

Comment: Google is your friend. Balance atoms first then electrons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iodine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine) exists as a diatomic molecule. This reaction indicates how the iodide ion is converted into diiodine. Your reaction just indicates the electron transfer: you still need to balance the reaction.

You need an $\ce{I_2}$ molecule on the right hand side, which would need two iodide ions on the left hand side:

$$\ce{2 I- -> I_2 + 2e-}$$

To accept two electrons, we would need two $\ce{Fe^3+}$ ions:

$$\ce{2 Fe^3+ + 2 e- -> 2 Fe^2+}$$

Now we have a balanced reaction. All the electrons donated by iodine are accepted by iron. Adding up the two reactions and cancelling the electrons gives us:

$$\ce{2 Fe^3+ + 2I- -> 2 Fe^2+ + I_2}$$